# How to implement JWT for Guest Users

Tags: laravel, security, jwt

I am working on API's in lumen. These api's will be consumed by android app. I just need discuss about security that how can i protect my application. So, first i will tell basic structure and current implementation.
It is a multi language site. So, in first request (Generate Token) I am expecting **App ID**, **device_id** a signed header (like HMAC authentication, this HMAC is generated in postman pre request script based on different parameters) from user. According to the passed **app_id** a site_id, language_id is fetched and based on that a JWT token is generated. Please let me know if it is fine and what to do when user is logged in. Do, i have to update token in that case and i also wanted to know about the refresh tokens how i can implement them.

Comment: have you tried this https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth?

Comment: @ZeroOne, i am asking about implementation and i am already using this package to generate token